# Reset my infura project api key and secret id?

Tags: infura

```
https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<api_key>
```

Can i access my project wallet using a newly generated api key and secret id? Is it possible to reset these credentials in infura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your project's wallet using any API key, provided you have the wallet's correct private key or Mnemonic phrase.

AFAIK, you can not reset the Infura credentials, but you can always create new projects.